# Happy Anniversary Freelancing SE

Tags: discussion

Happy (slightly belated) birthday Freelancing SE. On June 4th, 2013 Freelancing had successfully made it through to Public Beta on Area 51 and the site became a part of the Stack Exchange Network.

To celebrate you'll see a banner displayed on your main site for the next month which will redirect visitors who click to this post. If you have stories to share, favorite questions or answers from the past decade, etc. please share them below as answers.

Congratulations to you all.

Comment: Yeah, this site is basically dead at this point. Utterly neglected by the CMs and less than a handful of questions each month.